# Строка подключения для .Net EF MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

Пытаюсь в ручную собрать строку подключения для контекста используя известный пример:

var Builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

```
        // Set the properties for the data source.
        Builder.DataSource = "localhost";
        Builder.InitialCatalog = "CustomerManager";
        Builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        Builder.UserID = "root";
        Builder.Password = "111111";
        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        var EntityStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        //Set the provider name.
        EntityStringBuilder.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        EntityStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = Builder.ToString();

        // Set the Metadata location.
       // EntityStringBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/";

        //return the string now
        CustomerManagerContext = new CustomerManagerContext(EntityStringBuilder.ToString());
```

Получаю ArgumentException с сообщением: Ключевое слово не поддерживается "provider".
Если строка подключения передается в контекст не через конструктор, а через файл конфигурации, то тогда все нормально работает, но нужна возможность задавать строку подключения в программе в ручную. Помогите с этим разобраться, вот файл конфигурации:

```html
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  
    <providers>
      
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
    
      </provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=111111;database=CustomerManager;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Т. к. используется mysql, то, по идее, следует использовать класс [MySqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.htm). У него нет свойства `Provider`. А тот билдер, что вы сейчас используете, предназначен для SqlServer. PS: разглядел, что проблема в `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: Вот я про это думал, только не знал где его взять этот builder.